# Bullets are not working in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I found another post in stackoverflow ('[How to create bullets in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567250/how-to-create-bullets-in-pygame)') that shows on how to add bullets, however, they are not working, the program complains with the following error 'Invalid syntax' what could I be doing wrong? Please Help Me! Here is the code:

```
import pygame, random, sys
from pygame.locals import *


TEXTCOLOR = (0, 0, 0)
FPS = 60
BADDIEMINSIZE = 8
BADDIEMAXSIZE = 70
BADDIEMINSPEED = 1
BADDIEMAXSPEED = 12
ADDNEWBADDIERATE = 1
PLAYERMOVERATE = 3
WINDOWWIDTH = 1280
WINDOWHEIGHT = 780
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
background = pygame.image.load("background.png")
backgroundRect = background.get_rect
background_position = [0, 0]
bulletpicture = pygame.image.load("bullet.png")
bullets = []

def terminate():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

def waitForPlayerToPressKey():
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                terminate()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE: # pressing escape quits
                    terminate()
                return

def playerHasHitBaddie(playerRect, baddies):
    for b in baddies:
        if playerRect.colliderect(b['rect']):
            return True
    return False

def drawText(text, font, surface, x, y):
    textobj = font.render(text, 1, TEXTCOLOR)
    textrect = textobj.get_rect()
    textrect.topleft = (x, y)
    surface.blit(textobj, textrect)

# set up pygame, the window, and the mouse cursor
pygame.init()
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('Dodger')
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

# set up fonts
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)

# set up sounds
gameOverSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('gameover.wav')
click_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("pistol.wav")




# set up images
playerImage = pygame.image.load('ship.png')
playerRect = playerImage.get_rect()
baddieImage = pygame.image.load('baddie.png')
background_image = pygame.image.load("background.png") .convert()

# Copy image to screen
screen.blit(background_image, background_position)

# Set positions of graphics
background_position = [0, 0]

# show the "Start" screen
drawText('Dodger', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3), (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3))
drawText('Press a key to start.', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 30, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) + 50)
pygame.display.update()
waitForPlayerToPressKey()


topScore = 0
while True:
    # set up the start of the game
    baddies = []
    score = 0
    playerRect.topleft = (WINDOWWIDTH / 2, WINDOWHEIGHT - 50)
    moveLeft = moveRight = moveUp = moveDown = False
    reverseCheat = slowCheat = False
    baddieAddCounter = 0



    while True: # the game loop runs while the game part is playing
        score += 1 # increase score



        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                terminate()



            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == ord('z'):
                    reverseCheat = True
                if event.key == ord('x'):
                    slowCheat = True
                if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                    moveRight = False
                    moveLeft = True
                if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                    moveLeft = False
                    moveRight = True
                if event.key == K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                    moveDown = False
                    moveUp = True
                if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                    moveUp = False
                    moveDown = True

            if event.type == KEYUP:
                if event.key == ord('z'):
                    reverseCheat = False
                    score = 0
                if event.key == ord('x'):
                    slowCheat = False
                    score = 0
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                        terminate()

                if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                    moveLeft = False
                if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                    moveRight = False
                if event.key == K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                    moveUp = False
                if event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                    moveDown = False
                if event.key == ord('p'):
                    click_sound.play()
                    bullets.append([event.pos[0]-32, 500])



            if event.type == MOUSEMOTION:
                # If the mouse moves, move the player where the cursor is.
                playerRect.move_ip(event.pos[0] - playerRect.centerx, event.pos[1] - playerRect.centery)

        # Add new baddies at the top of the screen, if needed.
        if not reverseCheat and not slowCheat:
            baddieAddCounter += 1
        if baddieAddCounter == ADDNEWBADDIERATE:
            baddieAddCounter = 0
            baddieSize = random.randint(BADDIEMINSIZE, BADDIEMAXSIZE)
            newBaddie = {'rect': pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, WINDOWWIDTH-baddieSize), 0 - baddieSize, baddieSize, baddieSize),
                        'speed': random.randint(BADDIEMINSPEED, BADDIEMAXSPEED),
                        'surface':pygame.transform.scale(baddieImage, (baddieSize, baddieSize)),
                        }

            baddies.append(newBaddie)

        # Move the player around.
        if moveLeft and playerRect.left > 0:
            playerRect.move_ip(-1 * PLAYERMOVERATE, 0)
        if moveRight and playerRect.right < WINDOWWIDTH:
            playerRect.move_ip(PLAYERMOVERATE, 0)
        if moveUp and playerRect.top > 0:
            playerRect.move_ip(0, -1 * PLAYERMOVERATE)
        if moveDown and playerRect.bottom < WINDOWHEIGHT:
            playerRect.move_ip(0, PLAYERMOVERATE)

        # Move the mouse cursor to match the player.
        pygame.mouse.set_pos(playerRect.centerx, playerRect.centery)

        for b in range(len(bullets)):
            bullets.remove(bullet)

        # Move the baddies down.
        for b in baddies:
            if not reverseCheat and not slowCheat:
                b['rect'].move_ip(0, b['speed'])
            elif reverseCheat:
                b['rect'].move_ip(0, -5)
            elif slowCheat:
                b['rect'].move_ip(0, 1)

         # Delete baddies that have fallen past the bottom.
        for b in baddies[:]:
            if b['rect'].top > WINDOWHEIGHT:
                baddies.remove(b)

        # Draw the game world on the window.
        for bullet in bullets:
            if bullet[0]<0:
              bullets.remove(bullet)

        screen.blit(background_image, background_position)

        for bullet in bullets:
            screen.blit(bulletpicture, pygame.Rect(bullet[0], bullet[1], 0, 0,)

        # Draw the score and top score.
        drawText('Score: %s' % (score), font, windowSurface, 10, 0)
        drawText('Top Score: %s' % (topScore), font, windowSurface, 10, 40)

        # Draw the player's rectangle
        windowSurface.blit(playerImage, playerRect)

        # Draw each baddie
        for b in baddies:
            windowSurface.blit(b['surface'], b['rect'])

        pygame.display.update()

        # Check if any of the baddies have hit the player.
        if playerHasHitBaddie(playerRect, baddies):
            if score > topScore:
                topScore = score # set new top score
            break

        mainClock.tick(FPS)

    # Stop the game and show the "Game Over" screen.
    gameOverSound.play()

    drawText('You lose', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3), (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3))
    drawText('Press a key to play again.', font, windowSurface, (WINDOWWIDTH / 3) - 80, (WINDOWHEIGHT / 3) + 50)
    pygame.display.update()
    waitForPlayerToPressKey()

    gameOverSound.stop()
```

I am a beginner on python and I'm almost there finishing my game.

Comment: please post a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) there is way too much code here. Also please copy the exact error message into your question (and highlight that part of the code) so it is easier for us to spot any mistakes

Comment: Voting to close as this is a trivial typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
screen.blit(bulletpicture, pygame.Rect(bullet[0], bullet[1], 0, 0)
```

Change this line, you forgot to close `)`

```
screen.blit(bulletpicture, pygame.Rect(bullet[0], bullet[1], 0, 0))
```