# Shoot bullet in the direction my ship is pointing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to get my bullet shooting in the direction that my ship is facing. I managed to get a bullet in the game using this very useful code: [How to create bullets in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567250/how-to-create-bullets-in-pygame)

Let me provide some code for reference. Below is the set of codes used to rotate my ship as-well as get it to move in said direction. Also, `Offset = 0`.

```
'''Directional commands for the sprite'''
if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]: offset_change += 4
if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]: offset_change -= 4
if pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
    y_change -= cos(spaceship.angle) * 8
    x_change -= sin(spaceship.angle) * 8    
if pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
    y_change += 5
if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
        x_change = 0
        y_change = 0
        offset_change = 0

'''changes X/Y based on the value of X/Y_Change'''

spaceship.angle += offset_change        
spaceship.startY += y_change
spaceship.startX += x_change
```

Below is the class the spaceship code is in.

```
class Spaceship():
'''Class attributed to loading the spaceship'''
    def __init__(self, char, startX, startY, Angle):
        '''Loads in the image and sets variables'''
        self.char = char
        self.startX = startX
        self.startY = startY
        self.angle = Angle
        self.space = load_item(self.char)
        self.drawChar()

    def drawChar(self):
        '''Draws the image on the screen'''
        #Code is from Pygame documentation 
        #Due to limitations of Pygame the following code had to be used with a few of my own manipulations
        rot_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.space,self.angle)
        rot_rect = self.space.get_rect()
        rot_rect.center = rot_image.get_rect().center
        rot_image = rot_image.subsurface(rot_rect).copy()
        gameDisplay.blit(rot_image,(self.startX,self.startY))
```

Now as part of the "How to create bullets..." link I previously mentioned I was thinking of changing

```
for b in range(len(bullets)):
    bullets[b][1] -= 8
```

to `bullets[spaceship.startX][spaceship.startY] -= 8` As it was my belief that that line of code represented `bullets[x][y]`. However I was presented with `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not float`.

I'm guessing my assumption is wrong. Any ideas you can suggest to get my bullet moving according to how I'd like it to be?

Comment: please consider looking into PEP008 (the python style guide). And a little tip: instead of repeated `==`, you can use `event.key in [pygame.K_RIGHT, pygame.K_LEFT, ...]`.

Comment: @CodingLambdas I'm not sure what I'm looking for in here..

Comment: I was writing an answer including a PointMass class, wich does a simple physics simulation, but I figured it would be too much. That's why there is just a simple answer below. The things in my previous comment are just tips to get your code to be more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b` is the index of the bullet in the list `bullets`, and `0` or `1` are the x and y coordinates.

You can update them as follows, with angle and speed changed to their values:

```py
for bullet in bullets:  # as 'bullets' is a list of lists
    bullet[0] += math.cos(angle) * speed
    bullet[1] += math.sin(angle) * speed
```

Another, more object oriented, approach:

```
class Vector(tuple):
    def __new__(cls, *args):
        if len(args) == 1 and hasattr(args[0], "__iter__"):
            return super().__new__(cls, args[0])
        else:
            return super().__new__(cls, args)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Vector(a + b for a, b in zip(self, other))

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return Vector(a - b for a, b in zip(self, other))

    def __neg__(self):
        return Vector(-i for i in self)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return Vector(i * other for i in self)

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return self.__mul__(other)

    def __div__(self, other):
        return Vector(i / other for i in self)

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        return self.__div__(other)


class Bullet(object):
    def __init__(self, position, angle, speed):
        self.position = Vector(position)
        self.speed = Vector(math.cos(angle), math.sin(angle)) * speed

    def tick(self, tdelta=1):
        self.position += self.speed * tdelta

    def draw(self):
        pass  # TODO


# Construct a bullet
bullets.append(Bullet(position, angle, speed)

# To move all bullets
for i in bullets:
    i.tick()  # or i.tick(tdelta)
```

Comment: This somewhat works, and I do apologise for my code, still learning (1st Year @ Uni). It works to some extent but for certain angle it doesn't work as it should and of course rotating my ship causes the bullet to jitter and change directions sometimes

Comment: Ok, I think I'll add another approach, that adds a `Bullet` class.

Comment: @Lucky38i If you think about it, its logical that this happens: If you supply the angle of the ship, instead of storing the angles of all bullets, you are consequently changing the angle of all bullets too. I should have added, that you should store the angles for them in the list that represents a bullet as well, or somewhere else.

Comment: I'll give your class approach a look then get back to you, greatly appreciate the help

Comment: alright I managed to slightly wrap my head around what's going on here but can't seem to figure out how to blit it on the screen

Comment: Thats what the `draw` method is for. You'll have to implement it, I'd use [`pygame.draw.circle`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.circle) for that. You'll have to call this method for all bullets in your mainloop.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to why I'd draw a circle if my bullet is an image. Under `def draw(self):` I put `gameDisplay.blit(bulletpic,self.position)` instead. In the main code I put `bullets.append(Bullet((spaceship.startX+30, spaceship.startY-5),spaceship.angle - 15,8))` and to draw I put `bullet.draw()` under the for statement

Comment: @Lucky38i yup. Didn't know that you have an image. You may rotate it via `pygame.transform.rotate`.

Comment: few alterations and I got it working, appreciate the help