# stuck on pygame.draw.rect()

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

im trying to draw a shape with pygame.draw.rect() when i press a key but the shape wont stay when another key or event happen and also the shape moves where ever the ship moves but i only want it to move when i shot it and stay in that place and the shape wont stay on the surface after i release that key

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_hight = 600
colors = {"black": (0, 0, 0), "white": (255, 255, 255), "green": (0, 255, 0), "red": (255, 0, 0), "blue": (0, 0, 255)}
ship_width = 75
ship_hight = 72
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_hight))
pygame.display.set_caption('test')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

shipimg = pygame.image.load('D:\\index.png')

def ship(x, y):
    gameDisplay.blit(shipimg, (x, y))



def Game_Loop():
    x = (display_width * 0.41)
    y = (display_hight * 0.8)
    x_change = 0
    fire_start_y = y - ship_hight
    fire_start_x = x + (ship_width / 2)

    GameExit = False


    while not GameExit:
        if fire_start_y < 0:
            fire_start_y = y - 30
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                GameExit = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -5
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 5

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 0
        x += x_change

        gameDisplay.fill(colors["white"])

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_x:
                pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, colors["green"], [fire_start_x, fire_start_y, 2, 10])

        ship(x, y)
        if x <= 0 or x >= display_width - ship_width:
            x -= x_change
        fire_start_y -= 5
        fire_start_x = x + (ship_width / 2)


        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)


Game_Loop()
pygame.quit()
```

i tried this code to manage the disappearing problem but it made it worse 
as it ever lopping after i press the key once

```
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_x:
                pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, colors["green"], [fire_start_x, fire_start_y, 2, 10])
                fire_start_x = x + (ship_width / 2)
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_x:
                pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, colors["green"], [fire_start_x, fire_start_y, 2, 10])
                fire_start_x = x + (ship_width / 2)
```

Comment: If you just want to shoot bullets, then create a list and append `pygame.Rect`s (which represent the bullets) when you shoot. To move the rects upwards, use a `for` loop and decrease their `y` values.

Comment: I can show you an example, but it's not really clear if you really just want to shoot some bullets. Please describe your goals in detail.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fire many bullets when a button is held down use this code.

```
if pygame.key.get_pressed[pygame.K_x] != 0:
    # Add code to add Rect objects to a list.
    # Add in code to add the Rect objects in intervals.
```

In the code above you must add code so that you don't add in a rect object during every interation of the game loop. If you don't you will fire 60 bullets in a second or 1 bullet per frame which may or may not be too many.

If you want to fire one bullet for every keydown event use this code.

```
if pygame.event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if pygame.event.key == pygame.K_x:
        # Add code to add Rect objects to a list.
```

During the rendering of your game loop you need to render the rect objects.

```
for bullet in bullets:
    # Blit the bullet to the screen 
    # Increment/Decrement the x/y values so they move.
```

Of course you need handling to remove bullets from this list. You will also need to code in collision detection.

If you explain more and in more detail I will add to the answer.
Hope this helped!

EDIT: Okay you need to use the first block of code to have "pressed-down" firing of bullets. Add these rect objects to a list.

```
if pygame.key.get_pressed[pygame.K_x] != 0:
    bullets.append(pygame.Rect(x, y, 10, 3))
    # Add in a time delay.
```

Make sure you create the bullets list. The x and y value will be wherever the you want the bullets to fire from in relation to the ship.

Now render them.

```
for bullet in bullets:
    window.blit(bullet, [bullet.x, bullet.y])
    bullet.x += 3 # This will make the bullet go EAST.
```

Remove bullets which have gone off of the screen.

```
for bullet in bullets:
    if bullet.x < 0 or bullet.x + bullet.width > window_width:
        bullets.remove(bullet)
    # Add in some collision detection with other ships here.
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: ok here is my goals i want to shot bullets as long as i press a specific key assume that key is x and i want that bullet to start from another object lets say that object is a ship so as long as the bullet is shot the bullet direction wont change only its shooting direction change i hope that gives you more details

Comment: Just saw your answer. Nevermid.

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys but i found the answer i am looking for in this [How to create bullets in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567250/how-to-create-bullets-in-pygame)

creating a list of bullets and then use append method to add direction fo every bullet i shot when i press x key and removeing them from the list if they are out of my game surface

here is what my code looks like now

```
bullets = []
bullet_width = 2
bullet_hight = 10
def Game_Loop():
    x = (display_width * 0.41)
    y = (display_hight * 0.8)
    x_change = 0
    bullet_y = y - (ship_hight/2)

    GameExit = False

    while not GameExit:
        bullet_x = x + (ship_width / 2)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                GameExit = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -5
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 5
                if event.key == pygame.K_x:
                    bullets.append([bullet_x,bullet_y])
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 0
        x += x_change

        gameDisplay.fill(colors["white"])

        for bullet in bullets:
            pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, colors["green"], (bullet[0], bullet[1], bullet_width, bullet_hight))

        ship(x, y)
        if x <= 0 or x >= display_width - ship_width:
            x -= x_change
        for bullet in bullets:
            bullet[1] -= 5
            if bullet[1] < 0:
                bullets.remove(bullet)
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Never change a list while you're iterating over it. That leads to unexpected results and not all desired items will be removed. Either create a new list or iterate over a copy `for bullet in bullets[:]:`.