# Movement Of Multiple Images in Pygame

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I'm trying to build a small game using Pygame where a user will move a helicopter up and down and press space bar to shoot bullets. I already have the bullet image installed into the program and set the starting X and Y using `pygame.key.get_pressed`, but I'm trying to make it so multiple bullets can be shot across the screen at the same time. Here's the two parts of the code that deal with bullets that I have made, but they only have capacity for one bullet and when I press space again, the bullet just reappears and restarts it's motion.

```
pygame.key.get_pressed
...
if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
    Bullet = pygame.image.load("Images/Bullet.png")
    BulletX = HELICOPTERX
    BulletY = HelicopterY + 15
    BulletShoot = True
...
if BulletShoot == True:
    BulletX += 5
    SURF.blit(Bullet, (BulletX, BulletY))
    if BulletX >= 800: #800 is the width of the screen
        BulletShoot = False
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There are also lots of other questions about bullets on SO which you should check out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create bullets in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567250/how-to-create-bullets-in-pygame)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than storing each bullet attribute in a separate variable, you need to create a list of bullet objects. When the bullet's x coordinate goes above 800, then remove the bullet from the list.

Comment: This helped, but I still don't understand how to track each of the images, so I understand which one of them to move.

Comment: All of them, with a for loop.